# how to create links on spinner? - android

Tags: android, hyperlink, spinner

Is it possible to sent links for a spinner?
I searched around, mostly they are data inputs instead if you selected a certain spinner array then it'll link you to somewhere.
Is it possible to do it?

Also in my graphical layout it always says Item 1 then sub item 1 below.  Is there a way to change it?

since `android:text=""` works on textView I thought it would work here but guess I'm wrong

P.S. I'm trying to make the spinner so it'll be selected and links to a webView widget.
still thinking how it can be done but figured I couldn't even make a spinner to link yet.

Comment: oh ya I just saw that like right after I posted but actually how do I delete this post?
I'm reading that and see if I can get some idea on it first

Answer (score 1):

**You can Linkify the text** of the spinner using:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html

```
    TextView text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);   
    text.setText("Its not just hello world but 
                  the world is full of links....small links ,
                  big links...as... www.google.com ");
    Linkify.addLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
```

Now, the text www.google.com in the text will be linkified.

**OR you can use**

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
      int arg2, long arg3) {
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
         Uri.parse("http://www.google.com")));
 }

  @Override
  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

 });
```

inside onItemselected of the spinner **item selection**

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try that out still trying to get ideas in my head sorry I guess I asked the questions to earlier but thanks for the reply ^_^